# Why does my code running Selenium run correctly on repl.it but not on my Ubuntu VM?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a simple code that uses Selenium to download a dynamically rendered webpage.

```
from selenium import webdriver

Chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
Chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
Chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
Chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
Browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=Chrome_options)

Browser.get('https://example.com/hello')
Data = Browser.page_source
with open("webpage.html","w") as fout:
        fout.write(Data)
```

This runs correctly on repl.it, i.e. it downloads what is dynamically rendered, like a "Save As" on a browser.

However, when I run the same code in my Ubuntu 20.04 VM, I only got the static HTML page as if I'm running `wget` or "View Page Source".

I'm using Python 3.8 and Selenium 3.141.0 on both repl.it and VM, and my VM is running Chrome and ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.

Why does the same code not run correctly on my VM?

ETA: I noticed that repl.it took longer to complete `Browser.get`, while my VM completed it very quickly. Could it be for some reason, my VM did not wait for everything to finish loading?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized I needed to give the page some time to load. Seems like repl.it waits for the page to finish loading, but I needed to include a `time.sleep(10)` in my script on the VM so the page finishes loading.